# Summing over multiple columns

Tags: sql

Hi I have a table like this

```
Year Column1 column2 column3
 2015     A               B             C
 2015     D               A             B
 2016     F               C              A
```

And I need to be able to sum across the column how many times a certain subset shows up. What I want the summary table to look like is this

```
Year Letter count
2015  A        2
2016  A        1
2015  B        2
```

If anyone can help me with this I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` to break the data apart, and then `group by` to bring it back together:

```
select year, letter, count(*) 
from ((select year, column1 as letter from t) union all
      (select year, column2 as letter from t) union all
      (select year, column3 as letter from t) 
     ) yc
group by year, letter;
```

For a set of particular letters, add a `where letter in ('A', 'B')` clause.